# SharePoint Page access and multiple WFE's

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When a user access's SharePoint, he/she hits one of the wfe's using the url. Then if another user hits a different wfe the information is identical. 
How is this all managed?
If I use SPD to brand a page then why are changes available on both WFE's.

Any resources out there to explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to understand.

- [Web front end](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-knowledge-base/glossary/web-front-end-server-wfe): A web server that handles web page requests from users, processes the request and returns the data. If we have more than one WFE in the farm then Loadbalancer will play a role. Loadbalancer will distribute the load between the servers. WFE don't store any user data
- Content Database: an SQL server database which will store all the SharePoint content. One Content Database to attached to one web application only. One Web application can have more than 1 Content DB.

So when you deploy the pages(designed by the SPD) and deploy to SharePoint, it stores the information in Content DB.

Now User A requests a Page > it request lands on LoadBalancer > Direct to the One of WFE > WFE make a request to Database and get the information and process it > return to customer.

So information source is same for both WFE.

Comment: When there are multiple WFE, Application Server and Timer Jobs, is there a concept what controls the entire farm, i.e. whos in charge?
Do timer jobs run on all WFE's and Application server?

Comment: there is not a single person who is controlling it...It is basically The SharePoint timer job process - OWSTimer.exe. Which make sure all the task execute in a timely manner. Some Jobs run on all the server in the farm and some runs on dedicated server...You can control it which timer job run on which server...it is by content database level. this one is good article. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/sharepoint-2010-internals-timer-jobs2/

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint stores the information displayed to the user (and most configuration settings etc.) in centrally stored databases, hence the reason that the information displayed from each web front end server to a user is the same.

There's a useful poster that Microsoft provide showing both physical and logical architecture at http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/9/8196850D-45C7-48AB-A84A-918C7C2C3530/sps-2013-architecture-overview.pdf.